# Как сделать медиа запрос по высоте?

Tags: css, вёрстка, media-queries

Можно ли задать `@media queries` по высоте. К примеру мы можем задать ,

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1600px){}
```

Т.е если экран меньше 1600 то эти стили

Можно ли, как то задать если высота меньше 720 то эти стили
Если да, то как высчитывается высота. Т.е высота браузера( вместе с закладками , поиском и.т.п) либо без них?

Answer (score 3):

Конечно можно, а в некоторых случаях и нужно

[Почитать](https://webref.ru/css/media)

```css
@media only screen and (max-height: 300px) {
  body {
    background: red;
  }
}
```